# MariaDB foreign key issue

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mariadb

Been awhile since I've had to create/define a database, so ignore my lack of understanding. Basically, I have a table that has a few fields, one of which is a hash which references another table with the same hash, and the hash value. I believe the problem lies in the fact that I'm using the foreign key to references the non-primary key in the secondary table. So my question is this: how do I set up this relationship? Below is a minimum example to create my issue:

```
-- first table, imagine this as the hash value (should I remove the r_id,
-- and make the r_hash a unique & primary key?)
create table rx(
 r_id int(10) auto_increment primary key,
 r_hash varchar(175) default null,
 r_val  varchar(175) default null
);

create table cx(
 c_id int(10) auto_increment primary key,
 c_name varchar(175) default null,
 querystr varchar(175) default null,
 r_c_hash varchar(175) default null,
 constraint r_fk foreign key(r_c_hash) references rx(r_hash)
);
```

And the classic error that I somehow still can't get around:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test2.cx' (errno: 150)
```

EDIT:

Just for clarification, an example row from rx will look like this:

```
1 |  asdkjIOFJE93fijflskf | anexamplehashvalue
```

and an example row from cx may look like this:

```
1 | name_of_file | queryString=yes&1=3 | asdkjIOFJE93fijflskf
```

which as you can see, the hash values match which is all I need.. Do I recreate the rx table with the hash as the PK and make it unique? or can I keep the structure of the tables as it already is?

Comment: If `rx` is a key-value store, this is only the beginning of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not referencing the primary key?  That really is what primary keys are for.

If you really, really need to use a different key, then you should define a unique index on it:

```
create unique index unq_rx_r_hash on rx(r_hash);
```

Comment: Let me ask you this though: the primary key on rx will just be an auto-incrementing int.. so will the db know to make the connection between the r_c_hash and the r_id?

Comment: @user2879041 . . . No, when you insert a row in `cx` you would put the appropriate value of `r_id` for the reference.

Comment: Okay so I think that's the real issue then.. I'm inserting into these tables at the same exact time.. think I'll need to rethink the rx table structure